# Powershell extract log file content for last n minutes

Tags: powershell, date, parsing, logging, select-string

I am trying to extract content from a log file for last n minutes and perform another set of actions based on the extracted data. My Log file look like below:

```
2019-01-25 02:45:55,018 [5 - -22d] INFO Server - Some information
2019-01-25 02:45:55,018 [5 - -22d] INFO Server - Some information
2019-02-25 02:45:55,018 [5 - -22d] INFO Server - Some information
2019-02-25 19:09:50,018 [5 - -22d] ERROR IOException Some Error
2019-02-25 02:45:55,018 [5 - -22d] INFO Server - Some information
```

I have created a task scheduler which runs every say 1 minute and checks the log file for the specific error in last 1 minute and performs the next action.What matters here is the time, I want to compare the current time with the log file time when the error occurred. What I have tried is below:

```
 $data=Get-Content $log | Select-String -Pattern 'String to search error'
   foreach ($line in $data){
     $logdate = Get-Date ($line -split ',')[0] -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
      Write-Output $logdate
       if($date -eq $logdate){
          Write-Output "Some action"          
       }   
   }
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same results? Can the community shed some light as I am not much familar with powershell? Also tried various other cmdlets "LastWriteTime, Get-Content, regex-, etc"

Comment: There are several solutions within powershell if youre running into speed limits. The solution depends a little bit of your powershell version, the underlying .net versions and the file. How big is the file and how many records are from the current day?

Assuming that the logfile is big I do recommend the systen io Streamreader class, see

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netcore-3.1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462561/system-io-streamreader-vs-get-content-vs-system-io-file

Comment: Try `foreach($line in $data){<Stuff you already put up to the if> if((get-date).addminutes(-<x amount of minutes>) -gt $logdate){#do something}}`

Comment: Thanks Neko, that's how I am currently doing it. Is there a way to compare the current time with the time when error occurred(i.e in logs), it could be now or just a minute back.

Answer (score 1):

There are alternative ways of doing this.

Convert each date found to DateTime object and compare against a certain reference date. Use `-like` to limit the search to only lines that contain the specified search term.

```
$referenceTime  = (Get-Date '2019-02-25 19:09:00').AddMinutes(-10)
$wildcardSearch = '*ERROR*'
Get-Content -Path 'D:\SomeLog.log' | 
Where-Object { $_ -like $wildcardSearch -and (Get-Date ($_ -split ',')[0]) -gt $referenceTime }
ForEach-Object { 
    # do something here, for demo just output the 
    $_
}
```

Or, since the dates and times are all in sortable format, you don't have to convert to DateTime.
This demo uses regex `-match` to compare the search term

```
# the reference time in sortable string format, as are the dates in the log
$referenceTime = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date '2019-02-25 19:09:00').AddMinutes(-10)
# simple words like ERROR do not need escaping, but other search terms might
$regexSearch   = [regex]::Escape('ERROR') 
Get-Content -Path 'D:\SomeLog.log' | 
Where-Object { $_ -match $regexSearch -and ($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $referenceTime } |
ForEach-Object { 
    # do something here, for demo just output the 
    $_
}
```

Or, use the fastest way of iterating through the lines in the log (again, using Regex):

```
$referenceTime = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}' -f (Get-Date '2019-02-25 19:09:00').AddMinutes(-10)
$regexSearch   = [regex]::Escape('ERROR') 
switch -Regex -File 'D:\SomeLog.log' {
    $regexSearch { 
        if (($_ -split ',')[0] -gt $referenceTime) { 
            # do something here, for demo just output the line
            $_ 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, the last option looks better, will try that.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you run the powershell script as administrator and start the script before you run your service for the first time.

And the following code will keep restarting the service when their is an "ERROR IOException"

```
Get-Content -Tail 0 -Path $log -Wait | % {
    if($_ -like "*ERROR IOException*"){ # use * as wildcards
        write-host $_ -ForegroundColor Red
        write-host Restart your service
        Restart-Service -Name "__NAME OF YOUR SERVICE__" -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gerrit. I have provided the actual context, check the edited post. The log file can be in MBs and can contain the same error which occurred in past. I want the trigger an action if the error just occurred or within 1 minute. I tried the "Tail" option already, but its not a good option to check.

Comment: In Edited my post, can you try it again? Also notice that you dont have to shedule this script. it will keep running. And it will only monitor errors after you ran it. Also what is that action that you are taking when te error occurs? If this takes a long time and occurs alot you might want to start a new proccess to handle that error. If that is the case i will edit my post again. Also do not try to store it in the variable $data as it will not work in my example.

Comment: Ok then you need to put -tail 0 (i edited it also in my post) and make sure the powershell script is started before the service that is generating the log file.